# Constant in Spring boot Application (Rest Application)

Tags: spring-boot, jax-rs, cxf

In a Rest application based on **spring Boot** ,we want to outsource the definition of some constant, we use now application.properties  (but it s fastiduex because we must go through @Value ("...")), Or declare them in Interfaces (static) .....

**Is there a simple way**? (It is **not** a spring MVC application, **100% RestFull**)

Comment: Hi, Some ideas?!!

Comment: I think you can have an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2324109/628006)

Comment: If you are working with Spring Cloud, then you can achieve this by using [Spring Cloud Config](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/).